# Show that for Turing computable functions $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is Turing computable too

Tags: turing-machines

> If $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are T, show that $f(n)^{g(n)}$ is Turing
> computable too.

I started by designing this machine: on the first tape I have n written in unary ($1^n$). Then on the second tape I write $f(n)$ and on the third one $g(n)$. I have one additional tape and the one with output (write-only).
The first step would be to copy $f(n)$ to the fourth tape (I'm on first position of $g(n)$, I'm going to the next symbol now). If on the third tape (with $g(n)$ I don't see blank, then I do the following: copy the string that was on the fourth tape $f(n)-1$ times (so if I had 111, I will have 111|111|111). And so on till I make it to blank on $g(n)$. The last step would be to copy string from the fourth tape to the output.

It seems to work but I'm not sure if the numbers of steps is $O(f(n)+g(n)+f(n)^{g(n)})$ since there are many returns when it comes to modyfying the fourth tape.

Could someone maybe give me a better idea how to do this?

Comment: Does not it suffice to show that a Turing machine can compute a power by repeated multiplications ?

Comment: But then will the time be $O(f(n)+g(n)+f(n)^{g(n)})$?

Comment: What is the time for a multiply ?

Comment: For multiplication, the way I do it, I get $O(f(n)+g(n)+f(n)*g(n))$. Here I would need to multiply $f(n)$ $g(n)$ times, but each time I multiply larger number, so it wouldn't be simply $f(n)^{g(n)}$.